# How to install MySQL gem on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, ruby, osx-leopard

What do I need to install mysql gem on Mac OS X ? I'm getting error "failed to build native extensions".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Install MySQL first, either by using binary or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Then:

```
gem install mysql2
```

Or:

```
gem install ruby-mysql
```

Just pick one and you are good to go.

---

**Edit**

In case you upgraded to MySQL version 5.6.12 on OS X, mysql2 will fail to compile. Solution is to downgrade MySQL as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17252887/45254

---

**Edit2**

In case you don't want to have mysql installed (maybe you use docker to manage your services) but do want to use mysql2 gem, you can instead install `mysql-connector-c` (using homebrew).

Comment: to install mssql with homebrew, type command : "brew install mysql".

Comment: In case if you have problems with mysql from mac ports run: gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/opt/local/lib/mysql?/bin/mysql_config

Comment: you don't want to downgrade mysql5. in Mysql8 `caching_sha2_password` is the default caching mechanism. if the client library does not support caching_sha2_password  you can change mysql authentication mechanism  to  sha256_password like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948350/phpmyadmin-on-mysql-8-0

Answer (score 15):

Some time back I wrote [some instructions on my blog](http://blog.iconara.net/2010/03/19/installing-the-mysql-gem-in-snow-leopard/) on how to do it in 10.6, but I think it's the same in 10.5.

I comes down to this command:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- \
  --with-mysql-config=/path/to/mysql_config
```

but you need to find the real value for `/path/to/mysql_config`. My blog post has a few tips, but there's one very important thing: you must have installed MySQL with headers. The official `.pkg` installer from MySQL doesn't IIRC. The best thing to do is to install MySQL with [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) (in the post I use examples from a MacPorts install, but that's because Homebrew wasn't mature when I wrote it).

If you install MySQL with Homebrew `mysql_config` will be located at `/usr/local/bin/mysql_config` and if you install it with MacPorts it will be at `/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql_config`.

I concur with the other answer that suggest that you install the `mysql2` gem instead of `mysql`. I think the command above should work for `mysql2` too.

Comment: still working on 10.15, although I ignored the `ARCHFLAGS`.

Answer (score 10):

if you already have MySQL server running elsewhere on the network and would like to still install the gem without having to install MySQL try the following

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

followed by

```
gem install mysql
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm running Mac OS X Lion with Homebrew.

The correct command to install a ruby gem is…

```
gem install mysql -- \ --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Mac OS X Mountain Lion, and installed MySQL with DMG.

```
gem install do_mysql -- \ --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include
```

and

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

This works for me ;)

Answer (score 4):

For me it did the most easy:

```
brew install mysql
gem install mysql
```

Brew is a package manager for Mac OS, a *must* have. Using it to install mysql first brings everything that the gem command is missing.

Comment: Worked for me on 10.10. This is much better than the accepted answer. mysql2 is not better than mysql if you need prepared statements. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21726231/1143830

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), and to me worked with the command bellow:

```
gem install mysql2 -- \ --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 3):

I installed MySQL with Homebrew and I had to use this to finally be able to upgrade the gem:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/opt/mysql/
```

Comment: This helped me but I had to use the directory of where mysql was. For me it was opt/homebrew/opt/mysql ...

Comment: was working on an old project and need to use specific version of mysql. mine was `gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/`

Answer (score 1):

I install MySQL with DWG mysql_config will be located at `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`

```
gem install mysql -- \ --with mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue while setting up MySQL gem on MacOs Mojave .This worked for me

1 Ensure Xcode command line tools are installed.
    `xcode-select --install`

2. For me the build was still failing with some header files missing which you have to install
   open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg

This link pointed to right direction. [Can't compile C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave/52530212#52530212)