# mysql2 gem fails to compile with MySQL 5.6.12 on OS X with Homebrew

Tags: mysql, ruby, macos, homebrew, mysql2

I updated all the packages I installed with Homebrew. MySQL got upgraded to 5.6.12 (from 5.5.27 or so):

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.12, for osx10.8 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

and now the mysql2 gem doesn't compile anymore:

```
$ gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429-perf/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
-----
mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429-perf/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
```

The file `mysql.h` is present in `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.12/include/mysql.h`. Any ideas what's going on?

The file `mysql.h` doesn't appear in `/usr/local` because the symlink seems to go deeper than it should:

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/include/mysql
lrwxr-xr-x  1 pupeno  admin  36 21 Jun 15:18 /usr/local/include/mysql@ -> ../Cellar/mysql/5.6.12/include/mysql
```

instead of

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.12/include
```

Having said that, I manually fixed the symlink and the compilation still failed. So I'm stuck.

Comment: Do you have the mysql developer library installed ?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I thought all development files were installed with thy mysql brew package. What am I missing?

Comment: Homebrew + rbenv has always worked for me. Could this be an RVM issue? Also, is `mysql.h` actually present where you think it is?

Comment: @tadman it worked until the upgrade and mysql.h is present where I described in the question. I'm not sure how rvm could be messing this up, but I wouldn't discard the option.

Comment: Same issue here found a resolution already?

Comment: Same issue, tried switching back to older versions of Ruby, but that didn't help, the only other thing I can think of is the upgrade of MySQL that messed things up.

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem, I managed to fix it. I did a lot of things, and I don't know for sure what it was, but going to MySQL 5.6.10 seems to have worked.

Uninstall MySQL 5.6.12:

```
brew unlink mysql
brew uninstall mysql
```

Go to the homebrew directory:

```
cd /usr/local
```

Go to version 5.6.10 (you can find a list of versions by running `brew versions mysql`:

```
git checkout 48f7e86 Library/Formula/mysql.rb
```

Then install mysql again:

```
brew install mysql
```

And now `gem install mysql2` works for me.

I've also installed mysql from source (`brew install mysql --build-from-source`), but that didn't solve it, but might be part of the solution.

Comment: iain's answer solved it for me. In homebrew 0.9.4 (not sure about other versions) you can use `brew pin mysql` after downgrading to 5.6.10, and that will prevent it from getting upgraded if you use `brew upgrade` regularly.

Comment: If you do a brew uninstall does that dump your datadir? I wasn't sure, so in my case I used `brew switch` to change back to my old mysql version I already had installed, as the upgrade to the latest version wasn't critical for me.

Answer (score 23):

just ;)

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 14):

This also seemed to work for me. It forces the gem to compile against 5.6.10.

```
bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/bin/mysql_config
```

Related answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9360181

Comment: This will only work if there actually is a mysql 5.6.10 installed at that path.

Comment: Worked great! Just need to make sure the path points to the version of MySQL that's installed. (In my case, I needed to compile against 5.1)

Comment: This rewrites `~/.bundle/config`.

Answer (score 11):

The top answer here is out-of-date... the brewers have fixed mysql:

```
brew update
brew upgrade mysql
gem install mysql2
```

This will update mysql to the latest version, which seems to work fine with the mysql2 gem on OSX.

Answer (score 11):

I had to specify the `ldflags` and `cppflags` for it to compile correctly, like this:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Comment: this was the only thing that worked for me in Jan 2020; note that the flags he indicates are listed when you run "brew info mysql@5.6"

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me too, possibly since upgrading to openssl 1.1
`gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include`

Comment: this solved my `ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` mysql2 error

Answer (score 6):

Much newer versions of MySQL are available, but for an older project install on Mac OS X Mojave, I still needed to run MySQL 5.6 and link against it in a Rails 5 app.

I configured bundler, then installed the bundle and was good to go.

```
$> brew install mysql@5.6
$> bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql\@5.6/5.6.42/bin/mysql_config
$> bundle install
```

Note that you'll need to update the MySQL release version in the path.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend this answer instead: [mysql2 gem fails to compile with MySQL 5.6.12 on OS X with Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238226/mysql2-gem-fails-to-compile-with-mysql-5-6-12-on-os-x-with-homebrew/17252887#17252887)

The problem is with the compiler settings in Homebrew's version of MySql. Original answer found here: http://www.randomactsofsentience.com/2013/05/gem-install-mysql2-missing-mysqlh-on-os.html