# Not able to use mysql2 gem with Rails 4.1.5 in RubyMine

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use the mysql 2 gem with Rails, so I added `gem 'mysql2'`. I am not able to install it using `bundle install`, and it gives me this error.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150307-17143-1jx7cob.rb extconf.rb 
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/Users/Ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-mlib
        --without-mlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-zlib
        --without-zlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-socketlib
        --without-socketlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-nsllib
        --without-nsllib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-mygcclib
        --without-mygcclib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/mysql2-0.3.18/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.18), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have no idea how to get it to work, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is some info on my computer.
`ruby -v` => `ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]`

`gem 'rails', '4.1.5'` (rails -v won't work)

`bundler -v` => `Bundler version 1.8.4`

OS: Mac Yosemite

Comment: how you installed `ruby`, through `rvm`

Comment: yes. Tried that before posting the question and still does not work.

Comment: ran: `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

Comment: I think I installed rails a while ago with home-brew.

Comment: What's your bundler version? Do you have `libmysql-ruby`?

Comment: @Jon I don't know. How could I find out?

Comment: try `brew install mysql`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238226/mysql2-gem-fails-to-compile-with-mysql-5-6-12-on-os-x-with-homebrew.

Comment: @Sontya Already have it (`Warning: mysql-5.6.23 already installed`)

Comment: @Jon Tried that and it gave me the same result as above.

Comment: I have tried with mysql 5.6 and 5.7 and rvm 2.1.5, and mysql2 0.3.20 and 0.4.2 latest, no luck.  Same error like dev tools not present.  Mysql installed with brew, and I redid install completely.  Just can't seem to find mysql or whatever dev library it needs for Mac OS X 10.11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem, I was running `rails server` in RubyMine, but for some reason, RM was using an old version of ruby. Changing the project's sdks worked perfectly!

Comment: Good to know that. :)

Answer (score 23):

For **Mac** Users:

```
brew install mysql
gem install mysql2
```

---

For **Ubuntu** Users:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
sudo gem install mysql2
```

*Installing the **libmysqlclient-dev** gives you the necessary files to compile the **mysql2** gem which is what Rails will use to connect to MySQL when you setup your Rails app.*

---

Finally, run `bundle install`

Comment: The OP says they're on OS X Yosemite in the question.

Comment: Thank you! Still seems to not work, with an error of: `Warning: mysql-5.6.23 already installed`

Comment: Then try this `rvm gemset install mysql2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72477/discussion-between-sharvy-ahmed-and-penne12).

Answer (score 5):

try to install 'libmysqlclient-dev' first

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

and after run

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you install your gems using bundler.

Run

```
bundle install
```

or simply

```
gem install mysql2
```

Then include it in your database.yml file

Comment: what was solution.  I'm stuck on this, tried uninstalling mysql2 gem, reinstalling, keep getting errormkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.

Answer (score 1):

Not an OS specific answer, but may help others:

Newer MySQL2 adapters (v0.4.x) are not compatible with Rails 4.1.5.
Specifying an older mysql2 gem (eg v0.3.x) fixes the issue:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.21'
```

Source: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/675