# mysql2 gem fails on bundle install, despite installing using `gem install...` command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

Here is the log from my `bundle install`

```
Fetching mysql2 0.5.2
Installing mysql2 0.5.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
...
...
...
Cannot find mysql_config at /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin/mysql_config
--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
--with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/admin/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found
here:

/Users/admin/development/locari/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.6.0-static/mysql2-0.5.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/admin/development/locari/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/admin/development/locari/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.6.0-static/mysql2-0.5.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds
before bundling.
```

So I do what it says, and run `sudo gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source`

```
$ sudo gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.5.2
Parsing documentation for mysql2-0.5.2
Done installing documentation for mysql2 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

And it installs fine! But when I run `bundle install` again, I get the same error. I've tried uninstalling, unlinking, and reinstalling `mysql` in brew.

What can I try next??

Comment: are you using windows? or LinuX?

Comment: @kishorecheruku MacOS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53747176/6392696

Comment: first try to install mysql in local. then you can try bundle install

Comment: @nourza Nothing from that page helps
@kishorecheruku I already said, it works when I install locally, just not when i run it as part of `bundle install`

Comment: This one $bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/bin/mysql_config

Answer (score 7):

Run these commands first:

`bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"`

Then run `bundle install` it works.

Comment: Running both of these commands separately just overwrites the first one. You need to put both of these install options into a single string on the first command.

Comment: This may depend on the bundler version, but when I put both in a single string it passes the entire string as a single parameter which then gets silently ignored when building.  The thing that worked for me is to just set `bundle config --local build.mysql2 --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`

Answer (score 6):

## Installation on M1 macs

This method helped me on **ruby v2.7.2** and **macOS Big Sur 11.4**.

### Install dependencies

```sh
brew install mysql zstd openssl
```

### Install the gem

```sh
gem install mysql2 -- --with-ldflags="-L $(brew --cellar zstd)/1.5.0/lib -L $(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" --with-ldlibs="-lzstd -lssl" --with-cppflags="-I $(brew --prefix openssl)/include"
```

As an alternative, you can modify bundler config:

```sh
bundle config --local build.mysql2 --with-ldflags="-L $(brew --cellar zstd)/1.5.0/lib -L $(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" --with-ldlibs="-lzstd -lssl" --with-cppflags="-I $(brew --prefix openssl)/include"
```

and run `bundle install`.

Comment: I don't have an M1 mac, but this worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

#### Use build options with `bundler`.

Try running this in your application directory:

```sh
bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

*This sets it just for your application, which can be handy for checking into your repo if others need a similar configuration. But you can also make it a global configuration on your computer by replacing `--local` with `--global` and it will apply to all your `bundle install` commands on your User account.*

#### Update

This actually didn't end up working for me but I'll leave it here because it *should* have worked. I basically just had to run:

```sh
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Instead of using bundler, even though setting this build config should have done this.

Comment: thanks, this helped me!

Comment: @LisaH You're welcome! You should upvote it if it helped you. ;)