# ld: library not found for -lssl while installing mysql2 gem

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, mysql2, failed-installation

I changed mysql2 version in my project's Gemfile from `0.3.20` to `0.5.2`. When I run `bundle update mysql2` I get the following error:

```
Fetching mysql2 0.5.2 (was 0.3.21)
Installing mysql2 0.5.2 (was 0.3.21) with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/ext/mysql2
/Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0 -r ./siteconf20190715-35076-13r30uh.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_DISABLED in mysql.h... no
checking for MYSQL_OPT_SSL_ENFORCE in mysql.h... no
checking for MYSQL.net.vio in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL.net.pvio in mysql.h... no
checking for MYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_NO_GOOD_INDEX_USED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_NO_INDEX_USED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_WAS_SLOW in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_OFF in mysql.h... yes
checking for my_bool in mysql.h... yes
-----
Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/lib
-----
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.4.0-static/mysql2-0.5.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

My setup:

**mysql**: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.42, for osx10.14 (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper

**OS**: MacOS Mojave 10.14.2

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem with the following command:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' -- --with-cflags=\"-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include\" --with-ldflags=\"-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib\"
```

and then

```
bundle install
```

**UPDATE:**

OpenSSL 1.0 [reached EOL on 2019-12-31](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/46876). After Mac OS and Homebrew packages upgrade you will need to specify paths to `openssl@1.1`:

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.5.2 -- --with-cflags=\"-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include\" --with-ldflags=\"-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib\"
```

Comment: I was having an issue with starting the rails server, I had an error that said `dependent dylib 'libssl.1.1.dylib' not found`. Your solution of reinstalling mysql2 with those flags worked. Thank you!

Comment: The update suggest using 0.4.4; that instruction works, but you can also use the 0.5.2 with the openssl@1.1 flags.  Perhaps the UPDATE needs adjusting to reflect this (instead of downgrading the gem to 0.4.4).

Comment: This works for `gem install`, but in my case it's still failing in `bundle install`.  I'm guessing it has to do with bundling gems into the vendor directory, so I'm looking for a way to set these parameters within bundle.

Comment: And the answer is `bundle config --local build.mysql2 --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`, found by reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/56787988/776723 and https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/ee3ac6957c2ba4f7d7d33a251d58b191#gistcomment-2926747

Answer (score 3):

On macOS Big Sur I used the following commands to get the `mysql2` gem installed:

```
brew install openssl
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

Comment: this worked for me on Monterey, thx!

Answer (score 3):

Homebrew moved files around, here is what works now 2022-04:

- Macbook Arm M1
- MacOS Monterey 12.3.1
- Homebrew 3.4.7

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- \
--with-cflags=\"-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include\" \
--with-ldflags=\"-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib\"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it installing the missing the package `libssl-dev` (on a Debian derivative).