# `mysql2` gem- how to run benchmark files?

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

```
OSx v12.4
Ruby v2.6.0
XCode v13.4.1
`mysql2` gem, SHA e9c662912dc3bd3707e6c7f0c75e591294cffe12
```

I cloned the `mysql2` repo and I'm trying to run `ruby benchmark/active_record.rb` from the root directory.  I'm getting the following error:

```
/Users/richiethomas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-
6.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require': Could not load the 'mysql' 
Active Record adapter. Ensure that the adapter is spelled correctly in 
config/database.yml and that you've added the necessary adapter gem to your Gemfile. 
(LoadError)
```

I see the following in the repo's `Gemfile`:

```
group :benchmarks, optional: true do
  gem 'activerecord', '>= 3.0'
  gem 'benchmark-ips'
  gem 'do_mysql'
  gem 'faker'
  # The installation of the mysql latest version 2.9.1 fails on Ruby >= 2.4.
  gem 'mysql' if Gem::Version.new(RUBY_VERSION) < Gem::Version.new('2.4')
  gem 'sequel'
end
```

I tried running `bundle install --with=benchmarks`, and that completes successfully, however it doesn't install the `mysql` ActiveRecord adapter because my Ruby version is 2.6.0.

Although I know this shouldn't be necessary, I tried installing the `mysql` gem via the following command, as per [the gem's `README.md` file](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2):

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=-/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7
```

However, here I get:

```
library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I also tried installing `mysql` using the following command, as per [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69645924/2143275):

```
gem install mysql -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

However, I get an error related to `rb_cFixnum`, which I surmise is because the `Fixnum` class doesn't exist in my Ruby version (it appears to have been eliminated in 2.4.0, and I'm on 2.6.0).  Between these two errors, I feel like I can eliminate the possibility that the error is caused by a lack of the `mysql` gem.

On the chance that the root issue is an out-of-date linker file, I have updated both my OS and XCode to the latest versions available as of today's date.  The above errors occurred after I completed this update process.

My question is two-fold:

1. I notice that the error message references `config/database.yml`, which I'm accustomed to seeing in my Rails projects but which I don't see anywhere in the `mysql2` repo.  Does this mean I can only run the benchmarks if there's an associated `database.yml` file?  And if so, how would I run these benchmarks from (for example) a "Hello World"-type Rails project?
2. If I'm unable to install the `mysql` gem in conjunction with Ruby versions greater than 2.4.0, why does the `benchmarks/active_record.rb` file appear to rely on its presence in [this line of code](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/blob/master/benchmark/active_record.rb#L19)?  I would expect to be able to run benchmark files regardless of my Ruby version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not assume the benchmark tests can be run without some manual editing and corrections of the benchmark code. For example the file `setup_db.rb` contains hardcoded credentials which you will obviously need to edit.

Note also that you will have to run the setup file first, before you run anything else. For example the `active_record.rb` file seems to be using data from the `mysql2_test` table created with `setup_db.rb`.

The reference you get to `database.yml` is just a standard error message from the Rails codebase. It does not mean you need this file for the test. In fact you will most likely need to edit the `opts` line in the `active_record.rb` file instead, to point to a DB that can connect to something that is compatible with what you initialize in `setup_rb.rb`.

Also I would skip the `mysql` gem and just try to run it with `mysql2`, if you have it installed already. For this you have to remove any reference to `mysql` from the test code.

If you look at the `mysql` gem on Rubygems, [the latest version is from 2013](https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql/versions/). It is highly unlikely you will get it to run on any modern Ruby version. This also gives a hint of how outdated the benchmark code most likely is.

Further hints of out-of-date can be seen by looking at the git history of the files in the benchmark folder. They have not been updated since 2017.

**In summary**:

You will have to edit the benchmark code to make it work. The code
does not look like it is set up in a generalized fire and forget
manner, and is most likely outdated.

Do not install mysql, but instead mysql2. For questions related to
mysql2 installation issues, it's best to post a new question.