# Using prepared statement with MySQL2 gem?

Tags: ruby, prepared-statement, mysql2

How do I create prepared statements for `insert` and `select` queries in MySQL? I am using the MySQL2 gem, and my connection object looks like this:

```
 con = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "#{ENV['DB_HOST']}", :port => '3306', :username => "#{ENV['DB_UNAME']}", :password => "#{ENV['DB_PWD']}", :database => 'dbname')
```

Comment: Please ask only one question. How you generate a prepared statement with MySQL, why you should use prepared statements and what are their alternatives are three questions, and can't properly be addressed in a single question. I recommend reducing your question to the first one, then spend some time researching the other two as they'd be off-topic due to the amount of information that would need to be put in answers.

Comment: Its down to one question.. How to generate a prepared statement with MySQL2 gem in ruby?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, mysql2 gem does not have prepared statement support yet. The contributors are planning to add such a feature in a near future, as we can see by this Pull Request discussion:

https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/pull/289

If you **must** have prepared statements in your application, I would recommend you to read about Sequel, which has a very nice support for prepared statements and bound variables:

https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel

http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/prepared_statements_rdoc.html

**UPDATE**

As mentioned by @lulalala starting on version **0.4.0** [MySQL2 gem](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) supports prepared statements:

```
statement = @client.prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login_count = ?")
result1 = statement.execute(1) # Binds the value 1 to the placeholder 
result2 = statement.execute(2) # Binds the value 2 to the placeholder

statement = @client.prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_login >= ? AND location LIKE ?")
result = statement.execute(1, "CA") # Binds 1 and 'CA' to the placeholders, respectively
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: +1 I definitely second the recommendation to check out Sequel. It's a great ORM, and is core to what I do at work.

Comment: We totally agree on that @theTinMan ! I really like Sequel. It is robust and has a very nice interface to interact with =P

Comment: @Oatmeal That's ok, but keep in mind that is not the answer for your question. Using ActiveRecord is not the same thing as using mysql2 gem . It's the Rails default ORM. It's the same solution we purpose, but with a different ORM.

Comment: Yes I agree with you..... I want to know the importance of using prepared statements. I know they improve efficiency.

Comment: What I'm saying goes beyond the prepared statements importance =P I'm saying that we answered your question about mysql2 gem providing prepared statements support. If you decided to take another approach, using ActiveRecord, Sequel or any other ORM, it's totally up to you. But your original question **How to generate a prepared statement with MySQL2 gem in ruby?** was answered ;)

Comment: Seems in mysql 0.4.0 prepared statement is now supported https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/releases/tag/0.4.0

Answer (score 1):

You may also use mysql2-cs-bind gem, a thin wrapper of mysql2 which adds prepared statement feature:
https://github.com/tagomoris/mysql2-cs-bind

It provides `xquery` method that accepts arguments for the statement:

```
require 'mysql2-cs-bind'
client = Mysql2::Client.new(...)
client.xquery('SELECT x,y,z FROM tbl WHERE x=? AND y=?', val1, val2) #=> Mysql2::Result
```